# SFTP Download CSV File to memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, sftp

I have the following code:

```
sftp = Net::SFTP.start('ftp.test.com','luigi', :password => 'pass_code')

data = sftp.download!("luigi/List.csv")
```

This converts `data` to a string like so:

```
2015,This is, one value, test, 9820\r\n4003, This is also one value, test, 0393
```

I want to separate each row in my CSV file into an array value. This is my attempt:

```
data.split(/\r\n/)
data.each do |record|
    record.split(/,/)
end
```

This works for most cases, but it obviously gets screwed up for the first row in my csv file since the additional comma creates another value in my array:

```
2015,This is, one value, test, 9820
```

Because there is an additional comma that is not escaped, my array looks like this:

`["2015","This is", "one value","test","9820"]`

I want the above to look like this:

`["2015","This is, one value","test","9820"]`

or even

`["2015","This is one value","test","9820"]`

Is it possible, using `sftp`, to download my file into memory (not locally, I have nowhere to store it) and loop through each row in the file without the additional commas throwing things off? It seems that the root of the issue is I can't do something like:

`CSV.foreach(...) do |csv_row|`

But instead I have to use `sftp.download!` which only returns one string, not an array of "csv rows".

Comment: I think `[2015,"This is", "one value","test",9820]` is `['2015',"This is", "one value","test",'9820']`.. am I right ?

Comment: Given your data, how can you know that `[2015,"This is, one value","test",9820]` is the right result? There is no indication in the data.

Comment: You can't. That's my question...I know it's the right result because I can see the source file. I need to know how I can identify that in my code. If the file were saved locally, I could use the CSV gem which properly text qualifies each cell.

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are correct.

Comment: @Luigi I should be :-)